# Extracting number from the beginning of a string with regexp

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract the number at the beginning of a string in R. I have tried this:

```
> tt <- "51 - TS - Data estimated - see comments"
> grep('^[0-9]+', tt, value=T)
[1] "51 - TS - Data estimated - see comments"
```

Why is it returning the whole string and not just the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep` returns either the position or the value (of the entire input) if a pattern is found.

Try `gsub` or `gregexpr`+`regmatches` instead:

```
gsub("(^[0-9]+).*", "\\1", tt)
# [1] "51"

x <- gregexpr("^[0-9]+", tt)
regmatches(tt, x)
# [[1]]
# [1] "51"
```

Comment: I had come up with: `gsub('[^0-9]', "", tt)` but Ananda's better by far with regex than I. +1

Comment: this should work also. Not sure if it's any different. `gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", tt)`

Comment: @MartínBel - there's many ways to skin a cat: `gsub("(^\\d+).+","\\1",tt)`

Comment: @thelatemail sure: Here is another one: ```library(stringr)
str_extract("51 - TS - Data estimated - see comments", "[[:digit:]]+")```. I find this more intuitive but it probably depends of the data.

Answer (score 2):

**1) sub** Try this which removes the first non-digit and everything thereafter:

```
> sub("\\D.*", "", tt)
[1] "51"
```

**2) strsplit** or this which splits on non-digits and takes the first such component:

```
> strsplit(tt, "\\D")[[1]][1]
[1] "51"
```

**3) strapplyc** or this which extracts the leading digits:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc(tt, "^\\d+", simplify = TRUE)
[1] "51"
```